# O-notation with for-loop with modulo condition

Tags: java, big-o, modulo

My question is how to calculate the O-notation to this operation, where the two outer loops will go O(n^3) times. My question is what the o-notation is going to be when modulo is used in a condtion and the inner for-loop just runs when i is a factor in j.

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++) {
   for(int j =1; j <= i ∗ i ; j++) {
      if(j % i == 0 ) {
         for(int k = 0 ; k < j ; k++ ){
             sum++;
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still it will be counted as O(n^3).

Comment: Why wouldn't you define the mid-loop as `for(int j = i; j <= i * i; j += i) {`? Looks less scary and easier to compile.

Comment: Or just make j range from 1 to i, and multiply it by `i` when you want the value...

Comment: The task is from a Computer Science course, so I just want to calculate the o-notation to this specific method.

Comment: Can you give any kind of explanation for why it will still be counted as O(n^3)? Like why wouldn't the modulo-operation matter?

Comment: I'd actually expect it to be O(n^4) given that the inner loop is O(n^2).

Comment: @JonSkeet you mean the middle loop?

Comment: @Turing85: I mean the innermost loop, with k ranging from 0 to i^2-1.

Comment: @JonSkeet well. wouldn't it be O(n^5), since the middle loop has O(n^2) as well (ignoring the fact that the `if` condition cannot be `true` in each iteration)?

Comment: its n * n^2 * n^2 i believe if we ignore the if statement

Comment: @Turing85: But you can't ignore the fact that the if condition isn't true in each iteration. It's true i times for each outer loop. It's tested O(n^3) times (and I'll assume it's constant time for each check, so that's irrelevant if the overall result is worse than O(n^3)), but only passes O(n^2) times, so the inner loop only executes O(n^2) times, but is O(n^2) itself, leading to O(n^4) overall. At least, that's what I think...

Comment: @JonSkeet that is true but wouldn't you just add it in that case? So say its true n times or something it would be n^3 + n * n^2 which would still be O(n^3)

Comment: @Mitchel0022 it would be n^3 + n^2 * n^2. For each `i`, the `if`-condition is true exactly `i` times. For `i` running from `1` to `n`, you will end up with the [quadratic gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum).

Comment: @Turing85, so you're saying its O(n^4)?

Comment: @Mitchel0022 I think that O(n^4) is an upper bound. I am not yet sure that it is precise.

Comment: @Turing85, inst big O supposed to represent worst case in which case it would be right?

Answer (score 0):

It is `O(n^4)`.

The trick with this one is the `if (j % i == 0)`. Since `i` is pretty much `n` and `j` is going to range to `n^2` we know this statement will be true `n + (n-1) + ... + 1` times which is going to simplify to `(n+1)(n+2)/2` or `O(n^2)` which will in turn run a loop that runs `n^2` times. We then need to treat it as an addition, so we have `n^3 + n^2 * n^2`, this simplifies to `O(n^4)`.

If there is a fault in my reasoning please point it out, I am a little rusty.